Fit text container width to the exact length of the content when wrapping words
I encountered this situation where it seems the width of the text container goes full size if a word-break rule is applied.
<ul class="flex flex-col-reverse space-y-1 space-y-reverse transition-all">
  <li class="flex w-full items-end justify-between space-x-2">
    <div
      class="mb-0.5 flex size-7 shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-blue-500"
    >
      <img
        class="rounded-full"
        src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/1.jpg"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="w-full">
      <span class="ml-1.5 text-2xs font-semibold">
        <span class="ml-1 inline-block text-3xs font-normal">2023-10-16</span>
      </span>
      <div id="here" class="w-fit max-w-56 rounded-lg bg-[#161616] px-2 py-1.5 shadow-md">
        <p class="break-words text-xs font-medium">Who’s up for a movie night this weekend?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>


I've tried playing with more options for width, max-width, and min-width over the id="here" but I'm running in a loop, is there any way to fit the final length of the container to the exact amount of space the text takes?

